# How to do inter process communication using single bidirectional pipe in linux?

Tags: pipe, ipc

How do 2 processes communicate by using single bidirectional pipe, such that both the ends of the pipe could read and write.

Comment: Yet another valid question being closed for the wrong reason?  This question doesn't ask for learning material at all.  It simply asks for help!

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Pipes are unidirectional: you write at the write end, and read from the read end.

If you want bidirectional communication, use a [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), or two pipes.

You can use a pipe for bidirectional communication if both processes keep both ends of the pipe open. You need to define a protocol for whose turn it is to talk. This is highly impractical.